# CSS - target only one layer deep

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm working with Sharepoint at the moment and to say it's code structure/layout is a mess would be a huge understatement. It has a left navigation, and I want all items in there to be styled with a div around them (I'd target them individually, but Sharepoint has hundreds of widgets each with their own name class), for example:

```
<div id="leftNav">
    <div id="widget1">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div id="widget2">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried `#leftNav div { }` but that targets the sub divs too (and the sub divs of those divs) - is there anyway to just target the 'widget' divs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use the direct child combinator, `>`:

```css
#leftNav > div {
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I thought this didn't work in IE7 for some reason, but having just GOogled it... it does :)

Comment: @Nick: Yeah, it's IE6 that's the problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [child selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors) to target the direct child of the elements.

```
#leftNav > div
```